# Como exibir informações de uma classe

Tags: php, wordpress, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Quero mostrar os valores de uma classe mas não sei como acessar ela. 
O resultado do `print_r($this->order);` mostra

```
WC_Order Object ( 
    [status_transition:protected] =>
    [data:protected] => 
        Array ( 
            [shipping] => Array ( [first_name] => Alex [last_name] => Silva ) 
        )
```

Gostaria de retornar somente: o Alex e Silva.

Comment: Olá Thiago, a resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311782/3635 resolveu seu problema? Poderia dar um feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Duas coisas:

- Você não consegue acessar esse objeto diretamente pois ele é **protected**
- Se fosse public poderia usar o exemplo abaixo para ter uma ideia

```
class Foo {
    public $data = ['shipping' => ['first_name' => 'Renato', 'last_name' => 'Tavares'] ];
}
$ob = new Foo;
var_dump($ob->data['shipping']['first_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenho quase certeza que a duvida é sobre [woocommerce](/questions/tagged/woocommerce), se for o caso não domino isto, mas creio que resolvará usando o método `WC_Order::get_data()`, pois a variavel é protegida (protected), conforme a documentação da API do Woocommerce:

- https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#360

Então tendo pego isto poderá fazer um `var_dump` e observar o que foi retornado, provavelmente terá os valores.

No entanto olhando a documentação da API notei ambos métodos:

- [`WC_Order::get_shipping_first_name()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#584)
- [`WC_Order::get_shipping_last_name()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#594)

Ambos metodos aparentemente servem para pegar os dados que deseja, então seria algo como:

```
$nome = $obj->get_shipping_first_name();
$sobrenome = $obj->get_shipping_last_name();
```